# How to put flat shapefile of a glacier on top of 3D landscape/terrain

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface, snapping

I have imported with the add-on BLOSM the terrain showing a glacier in the Swiss alps. Additionally I imported with BlenderGIS the shapefile of the glacier shown in the terrain. Now I want to snap this model onto the 3D terrain and assume that the snap tool is the way to go. But as I am still very much beginner I am facing some major challenges:

- The imported model of the glacier is only one complex, flat face with hundreds of vertices (in the picture below I extruded it in z-direction). I assume I need to subdivide this one face before I can work with it and snap it to the terrain below, correct? How am I doing this. As said: it is one face surounded by hundreds of vertices.
- how do I use the snapping tool to "lay" the glacier smoothly on top of the 3D terrain? Is Snap with -> Face Project the way to go? If yes, how? I tested it with a a simple plane but it didn't work easily....

Thanks for helping an enthusiastic blender beginner.... :-)

[image: Screenshot]